# visual basic copy file without asking

Tags: visual-studio-2012, replace, copy

In visual basic I have a program that copies a file and moves it into another directory, if there is no file with that name and extension, it just moves it no problem. But when the same file is already in the directory, it asks if you would like to copy and replace or cancel, or copy and rename. How can I have it skip this an force it to replace the file?

This is what I am using for he moving code:

```
Dim directory = "C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop\helloworld.txt"

My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("helloworld.txt", directory,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```

Any way to avoid the notification? thanks. :D

Comment: Using the standard System.IO.File operations is not an option?

Comment: @Steve I don't truly understand how to use Visual Basic file system yet, please explain for me.

Comment: I mean. using the standard IO functions instead of the My.Computer provided ones you could fine tune the overwriting options, but you loose the Dialog showing the file copying process. So it is up to your preferences. Or your requirements. If your user has any say on the copying process or not

Comment: @Steve can you show me a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.IO namespace provides the [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method that allows the silent overwriting of the destination file

```
  Dim directory = "C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop\helloworld.txt"
  System.IO.File.Copy("helloworld.txt", directory, True)
```

Of course this removes the interface provided by the My.Computer method and your user has no way to stop the copying process. If your file is not very big then there is no much sense to provide such interface. But this is up to your preferences and requirements.